# PDAL is mixing Lat and Lon when using tindex

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, lidar, pdal, gdaltindex

I am trying to extract polygon representing the extent of my `.LAS` file. I am using `tindex` to do so.

When importing the resulting file, it looks like longitude coordinates are set as latitude and vice versa.

This is my code:

```
pdal tindex create --tindex output.shp  --filters.hexbin.edge_size=1 --filters.hexbin.threshold=4 input.las
```

Can someone help me understand my mistake?

Comment: Add a link to some .las file that can be used for reproducing the issue. It does not need to be your data that may be confidential.

Comment: Records in .las contain X, Y, and Z coordinates. What do you believe that X and Y mean in your data. X=Lon and Y=Lat or another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The las format defines that points have X/Y/Z coordinates and it defines how to include information about georeferencing https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/LAS_1_4_r13.pdf. However, it is not clearly defined what X and Y mean. Traditionally many GIS software consider that X is always longitude or easting and Y is latitude or northing. But sometimes the official axis order is respected and that means for example latitude-longitude for EPSG:4326 http://epsg.io/4326.

Because meaning of X and Y varies in real world point cloud data PDAL has options `in_axis_ordering`and `out_axis_ordering` in the reprojection filter https://pdal.io/stages/filters.reprojection.html#filters-reprojection. If tindex is swapping the axis I believe that you can add reprojection filter that just swaps x and y into your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @user30184. I didn't know about the filter reprojection. I'll add that to the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that is currently fixed in PDAL master and will be part of the next PDAL release. See https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/pull/3099 for more detail.